# Will my procedure be correct?

Tags: graphics, programming, education, recreational-mathematics

I am facing a problem when trying to solve the exercise of page 210 of the book **GRAPHICS with MATHEMATICA, FRACTALS, JULIA SETS, PATTERNS and NATURAL FORMS of the authors CHONAT GETZ and JANET HELMSTEDT**, 
which says in section 2) Use the diagrams below as starting points for constructing 3D fractals. ***I am trying to make part C***, 
the problem I have is that my final image does not think it is the correct result, this is based on the example that the authors show above, 
since it does not move on the z axis, but it does not I know if he should do it or not. I hope someone of you can tell me what I am doing wrong and 
I will try to correct it. Thanks for your support.

This is the code that I use

```
prb[{{x_, y_, z_}, {p_, q_, r_}}] := {{{x/2, 7/20 y, (3 z)/4}, {p/2, 
    7/20 q, (3 r)/4}}, {{x/2 + 5, y/4, (3 z)/4}, {p/2 + 5, q/4, (3 r)/
    4}}, {{x/2, (3 y)/10 + 7, z}, {p/2, (3 q)/10 + 7, r}}, {{x/2, 
    7/20 y + 13, (3 z)/4}, {p/2, 7/20 q + 13, (3 r)/4}}, {{x/2 + 5, 
    y/4 + 15, (3 z)/4}, {p/2 + 5, q/4 + 15, (3 r)/4}}};
```

For the first iteration

```
Graphics3D[Cuboid @@@ prb[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 20, 8}}]]
```

For the second iteration

```
Graphics3D[
 Apply[Cuboid, 
  Nest[Flatten[Map[prb, #], 1] &, {{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 20, 8}}}, 
   2], {1}]]
```

For the fourth iteration

```
Graphics3D[
 Apply[Cuboid, 
  Nest[Flatten[Map[prb, #], 1] &, {{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 20, 8}}}, 
   4], {1}]]
```

Images that I got

[image: first iteratioon]

[image: fourth iteration]

Comment: On what page in the book is the `prb[]` code ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk   In no page of the book does this code appear, that codeof the prb function, is part of the solution that I propose to solve the exercise that the authors propose, for that reason, it is my question to know if my procedure is correct or not